# Does OData 2.0 support "contains" in the filter

Tags: odata

I can see in the Basic Tutorial section of the [odata](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/) website that you can perfom a contains search using a filter

> GET serviceRoot/Airports?$filter=contains(Location/Address, 'San Francisco')

The API I am using refused this when I tried to use it. The API I am accessing is OData 2.0.

So I wanted to know if OData 2.0 supports the `contains` filter but couldn't find a list anywhere documenting the filters you could use e.g. startsWith, endsWith, contains

Answer (score 2):

My research led me to the only answer I could find which was to use `substringof` instead of `contains`. This is the end of the url call from the actual API I am working on. This results in searching for Items filtered by Description containing "69":

```
/logistics/Items?$filter=substringof('69',%20Description)%20eq%20true
```